# Is sharding done per database or collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to understand the sharding concept with respect to MongoDB. To understand the concept, lets say we have two scenarios:

1. I have two databases 'customer' and 'item'.
2. I have two collections 'customer' and 'item' in the same database.

Both 'customer' and 'item' datasets are huge (in TB).

My question is: In the above listed scenarios how is sharding designed and which one is preferred.

The examples I have come across talk about sharding with one collection. But when we have multiple databases/collections. How do we handle it?

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You enable it on db level but it is done on collection level. The first scenario would not provide any real benefits, not even for lock (which was why some people used to split out data). As for how to handle it: MongoDB will do that for you unless you choose to use tags and the such

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB distributes data, or shards, **at the collection level.**

See here:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/#data-partitioning

The procedure requires you to first enable sharding on the database level (which will not automatically shard any collection).

I think you should read through the docs carefully as sharding is by no means magic, and requires thorough planning and understanding of the mechanics.